# with root, open other process socket and get tcp_info with python?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tcp

I am trying to make a TCP performance monitor tool, the main value I want to extract is `tcpi_rtt`  [from tcp_info](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h#L148)

For in-process sockets, this could be obtained like `getsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_INFO)` in python

But what about external process? For an TCP connection, under python with root, I tried to `os.open(/proc/XXXX/fd/4)` the socket inode but fails `OSError: [Errno 6] No such device or address:`. This method only works for regular fd or stdin/stdout.

Are there any generic way to peek other process's tcp_info on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no python tool that I know of which does what you're asking for, nor is there an easy way I can think of involving parsing the proc directory yourself. As such, you could either implement a pure python version of the [ss command](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/misc/ss.c#L1371) yourself (or at least figure out how it calculates RTT from information in /proc/<pid>/net/*), or parse its' output. I'm more of a bash person so this is what I threw together to get a list of (RTT,PID) pairs:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import check_output as co

co("ss -tp > ss.out", shell=True)
rtts = co("cat ss.out | grep ESTAB | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -I {} ss -i 'src {}' | grep \"rtt:\" | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d : -f 2 | cut -d / -f 1", shell=True)
pids = co("cat ss.out | grep ESTAB | awk '{print $6}' | cut -d , -f 2", shell=True)

print zip(rtts.split('\n'), pids.split('\n'))
```

In the ss command the -t means show TCP connections and the -p means print process (PID) info. Using the -e option you could also get the inode number, which you can use to determine the file descriptor numbers in /proc/XXXX/fd/. For instance I have process 31117 running on my machine with file descriptor number 11 corresponding to a socket with inode number 31159:

```
# ls -lah /proc/31117/fd/11
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec 10 19:08 /proc/31117/fd/11 -> socket:[31159]
```

The reason you cannot "open" a socket file like /proc/pid/fd/4 is because these are all links which point to non-existent files. The only information you can get from them is the name (inode number) of the socket.

Comment: Thanks. `ss -eitp` revealed  the secret :)